# Event example from Polymer 3 devguide "Listener on outside elements" throws an exception

Tags: javascript, web-component, polymer-3.x

I've created example for the [snippets](https://polymer-library.polymer-project.org/3.0/docs/devguide/events#listener-on-outside-elements) from the Polymer 3 dev guide. This example doesn't compile as `_myLocationListener` is not defined and it is used in the constructor. The listener is also not defined inside the dev guide snippet.

How `this._myLocationListener` property should be initialized.

```
import {html, PolymerElement} from '@polymer/polymer/polymer-element.js';

/**
 * @customElement
 * @polymer
 */
class XcustomElementEventHandlingApp extends PolymerElement {
    static get template() {
        return html`
      <style>
        :host {
          display: block;
          border: dotted;
          background: aliceblue;
        }
      </style>
      <h2>Hello [[prop1]]!</h2>
      <button on-click="handleClick">Kick Me</button>
      <div id="child-el-01">Please, check the logs in Console (dev tools).</div>
    `;
    }

    static get properties() {
        return {
            prop1: {
                type: String,
                value: 'xcustom-element-event-handling-app'
            }
        };
    }

    constructor() {
        super();

        this._boundListener = this._myLocationListener.bind(this);
    }

    ready() {
        super.ready();
        this.addEventListener('click', this._onClick);

        const childElement = this.shadowRoot.getElementById('child-el-01');
        childElement.addEventListener('click', this._onClick.bind(this));
        childElement.addEventListener('mouseover', event => this._onHover(event));


        console.log('(this, the) custom element added to DOM.');
    }

    handleClick() {
        console.log('Ow!');
    }

    _onClick(event) {
        this._makeCoffee();
    }

    _makeCoffee() {
        console.log('in _makeCoffee()')
    }

    _onHover(event) {
        console.log('_onHover(ev) called');
        console.log(JSON.stringify(event));
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        window.addEventListener('hashchange', this._boundListener);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        super.disconnectedCallback();
        window.removeEventListener('hashchange', this._boundListener);
    }
}

window.customElements.define('xcustom-element-event-handling-app', XcustomElementEventHandlingApp);
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "xcustom-element-event-handling",
  "description": "event handling demo. From dev guide.",
  "dependencies": {
    "@polymer/polymer": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs": "^2.0.0",
    "wct-browser-legacy": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Following exception is thrown:

```
Uncaught TypeError: this._myLocationListener.bind is not a function
at new XcustomElementEventHandlingApp (xcustom-element-event-handling-app.js:36)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hope that latest edit did improve the question. I'm just started with Polymer 3 and am trying to run the dev. guide examples.

Comment: please add concrete code sample and error to the question body

Comment: Thanks! Example code and link to snippet are added to question body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the above example, the main idea is if you like to listen an event from outside of this custom element. You may set up a listener inside `connectedCallback` and remove it with `disconnectedCallback`, then assign a function in the element after event occure. 
Something like

index.html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/@webcomponents/webcomponentsjs/webcomponents-loader.js"></script>
    <script type="module" src="x-custom.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <button>This button not in the element</button>
    <x-custom></x-custom>
  </body>
</html>
```

x-custom.js:

```
import { PolymerElement, html } from 'https://unpkg.com/@polymer/polymer@3.0.0-pre.12/polymer-element.js';

class XCustom extends PolymerElement {
  static get template() {
        return html`<h2>Hello </h2> `;
  }

    constructor() {
        super();
        this._boundListener = this._myLocationListener.bind(this);
    }

    connectedCallback() {
        super.connectedCallback();
        window.addEventListener('click', this._boundListener);
    }

    disconnectedCallback() {
        super.disconnectedCallback();
        window.removeEventListener('click', this._boundListener);
    }
    _myLocationListener(){
        alert('This click comes from index.html - out of this element')
    }
}

window.customElements.define('x-custom', XCustom);
```

[DEMO](https://next.plnkr.co/edit/Yj9TKGBFp8KdpxBL?open=lib%2Fscript.js)

Comment: Thank you very much!
Additionally we can add an id to button to listen only button clicks:
window.document.getElementById('xyz1').addEventListener('click', this._boundListener);

Answer (score 0):

just to improve on HakanC's solution from Polymer 3 documentation, I managed to combine the ideas of each method without overriding any callbacks and managed to come up with the following method that goes in the class definition and is called externally; similar to interfaces in JAVA.

```
  public setOnClickListener(method): void {
    const self = this;
    $(self).on('click', method.bind(self);
    //  or self.addEventListener('click', method.bind(self)); if you use typescript
  }
```

simple enough for me...:)